# Print a deck of cards after they have been shuffled using a menu

Tags: java

My program has a menu with 3 choices. 1 is to display the deck(if the users enter 1 first a new deck will be displayed). 2 is to shuffle the deck without printing the deck. 3 just exits the program.  So for example to print a shuffled deck the user must enter 2 to shuffle then press 1 to display the shuffled deck. I cannot figure out how to print the shuffled deck without printing the new deck.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prog4 {

public static void main(String[] args){
    double menuOption = 0;
    int z = 0;
    MyDeck d1 = new MyDeck();
    MyCard c;
    System.out.println();

   while (true){
     Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);
       try{
          System.out.println("1.  Display the deck");
          System.out.println("2.  Shuffle the cards");
          System.out.println("3.  Quit");
          System.out.print("(Choose a menu 1, 2, or 3 : ");

          menuOption = option.nextDouble();

          if (menuOption == 1) {
             System.out.println("You selected display deck!! ");

   while(true){
     while(z<=12){
       c = d1.printDeck2(z);
       System.out.print(c.toString() + " ");
       z++;
    }
    System.out.println();  

    while(z<=25){
      c = d1.printDeck2(z);
      System.out.print(c.toString() + " ");
      z++;
   }
    System.out.println();

    while(z<=38){
     c = d1.printDeck2(z);
     System.out.print(c.toString() + " ");
     z++;
   }
   System.out.println();

   while(z<=51){
    c = d1.printDeck2(z);
    System.out.print(c.toString() + " ");
    z++;
   }
    if(z>51)
          break;   
   }
     System.out.println();
 }   
 else if(menuOption == 2){
    System.out.println("You selected Shuffle the cards!! ");
    c = d1.shuffle3();
}

else if(menuOption == 3){
    System.out.println("You selected exit!!");
    break;
}
else
 break;

}   

catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Invalid menu selected. Please choose menu 1, 2, or 3");
}

}
}
}


public class MyCard {
private int suit;
 private int rank;

private  String[] suits = {"S","D","H","C"};
private  String[] ranks = {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13" };

public MyCard(int suit, int rank) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
}
public int getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public void setSuit(int suit) {
    this.suit = suit;
}

public int getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public void setRank(int rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
}
public String toString() {
    return suits[suit] + "" +  ranks[rank];
}
}

 import java.util.Random;
public class MyDeck {
private MyCard[] cards;
int i;
int q = 51;
int z = 51;
public MyDeck() {
    i = 1;
    cards = new MyCard[52];
    int x = 0;
    for(int t=0;t<=3;t++){
        for(int s=0;s<=12;s++){
            cards[x] = new MyCard(t,s);
            x++;
        }
    }
 }

 public MyCard shuffle3(){
     Random randomNumber = new Random();
     int index = 0; 
       while(z>0){
         index = randomNumber.nextInt(q);
         break;
       }
         MyCard temp =  cards[index];
         cards[index] = cards[z];
         cards[z] = temp;
         MyCard temp2 = temp;
         z--;
         q--;
    return temp2;
}
     public MyCard printDeck2(int y){
     MyCard temp = cards[y];
     return temp;
}



}
```

Comment: Please try to format your code so that it's readable. Please use regular indentation with the same number of spaces.

Comment: OK, I've edited your post so that your code's indentations are regular. Can you see the difference? If we can read your code, we can better understand it and help you.

Comment: What does the shuffle method do? Should it return a MyCard object? Are you sure? Does it change the current MyDeck object? Or should it return a new MyDeck object? What do your instructions say? We'll need to see its code.

Comment: Hi Hovercraft sorry for the bad format first time posing just getting use to the 4 spaces for code. I just added the MyCard and MyDeck classes.

Comment: Ugh, you've un-formatted all the code I've formatted. OK, this one I'm leaving up to you. Please re-format the code. Be nice to us and our eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then create your deck in the first option, have a separate method called something `initDeck()` which does the deck initialisation.

Then when the option 1 is entered, check the deck is initialised, if not create one, then print it. If it is initialised, just print it.

When option 2 is chosen again check if the deck is initialised, if not create one then shuffle it. If it has been initialised, just shuffle it.

The point is, the method `initDeck()` should only ever be called once during the run time of your program.

Another option is to use a [Singleton pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html)

---

I wrote this without really looking at your code to much... I assumed that your option 1 was creating the deck with all those while loops but really it is just a mess.. its running the same code over just with a println in it. and could be replaced with something like (println condition may need a bit of adjusting) - it should also be within the Deck class and shouldn't need and input arugments:

```
while (z <= 52) {
      c = d1.printDeck2(z);
      System.out.print(c.toString() + " ");
      if(z%12 == 0)
          System.out.println();
      z++;
}
```

---

From your updated post, it appears that your shuffle method will only swap two cards and you only call it once so check carefully that your print method has actually swapped two cards.

To fix this you need to either rethink your shuffle method or call it x amount of times.